# How to set token as a global variable in flutter? so i can access the token wherever i want

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, bloc

I build an app using Firebase Authentication, after login, I have to save the token as a global variable so I can use that token wherever I want. I have tried to pass it as global variable in constant but I got stuck when because when I re-run the app, the token is erased.

thank you.

Comment: Save the token in a local database or in a shared preference and use it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the token inside the package `shared_preferences`:

> Wraps NSUserDefaults (on iOS) and SharedPreferences (on Android), providing a persistent store for simple data. Data is persisted to disk asynchronously

To save data:

```
addStringToSF() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('token', "token_value");
}
```

To read data:

```
getStringValuesSF() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  //Return String
  String token = prefs.getString('token');
  return token;
}
```

https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: after saving the token,how do you read it once and access it globally within app?

Comment: @griffins `String token = await getStringValuesSF();`